# Multi language dynamic page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having data with differents languages
My html is like:

```html
        <h2>{{customer.address}}</h2>
```

the customer.address can be in arabic, frensh or english or in arabic and frensh(predefined).
So I need a function who display the texte with lang according the data language.
I mean if the language is in english the html will look like:

```html
        <h2 lang="en">{{customer.address}}</h2>
```

Comment: An address is an address, addresses just show a place name, they don't have a language. (I mean, they may have attributes of a language, but `Rue Saint-Dominique` is still the name of that Paris street, whether you speak English, French or anything else. English people don't change it to "Saint-Dominique Road" when they post a letter to that address, they simply write the address the same as a French person would. So it's unclear what you want to indicate by this, really.

Comment: Also you haven't actually asked a question or explained a problem, we simply have a vague, aspirational requirement with no clarity or context. Are you asking how to automatically detect if a piece of text is written in a specific language? Or something else? We don't really know where you're stuck. See also [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: Couple of ways of doing it -

1. While saving user's data in DB, save the addresses in all the required languages and display the address as requirement.
2. Use Google Translate service and populate the address translated by Google

Answer (score 0):

As said ADyson, for addresses, better not to translate. If the person speaks arabic, "Rue Saint-Dominique" is still "Rue Saint-Dominique". If the person has input the address in GPS for France, Paris, it's still "rue Saint-Dominique". If the person has to ask to someone in the street when in Paris, better to say "Rue Saint-Dominique" to the french he will ask.

Now as said you have 2 options:

1. the simplest, usable because you have only 3 languages, that won't extend too much your HTML.
   instead of

```html
<h2 lang="en">{{customer.address}}</h2>
```

do something like:

```html
<h2><span lang="en">{{english.customer.address}}</span><span lang="fr">{{french.customer.address}}</span><span lang="ar">{{arabic.customer.address}}</span></h2>
```

Following language selected, let say EN, you hide FR and AR class.

2. you put in database with pointer.
   in database:
   ID (unic)
   FR xxxxxx
   EN yyyyyy
   AR zzzzzz
   Every single sentence you have in your website will have an unic number in database with its translation in all languages.
   Example
   ID 001
   FR Bonjour, comment allez-vous ?
   EN Hello, how are you?
   AR (i don't know, sorry!)

in your html

```html
<h2 data-lang="001">Hello, how are you?</h2>
```

You write a function which search all data-lang, and put the value coming from database. In the example I put the english because it's a fall back, in case of, you still have something in your html.

Comment: yes I'm searching for this function, because in arabic you need to translate everything and need to display the text from right to left with dir="rtl".

Comment: I set the dir to auto, now I need a function wich can set the value of lang deppending on the language predefined

Comment: which strategy do you have? all translation in HTML from beginning, or translation coming from a database?